# Show that $X=\mathbb R\cup\{x\}$ is non-Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

Let $X=\mathbb R\cup\{x\}$ and let $T=\{\,U\subseteq\mathbb R \mid \text{$U$ is open in $\mathbb R$}\,\} \cup\{X\}$

> A) Is $T$ a toplogy on $X$?
>
> B) Show that $X$ has the property that every sequence has a limit point.
>
> C) Show that $X$ is non-Hausdorff.

I tried:

For A) the topological spaces I was supposing three axioms

1. $X$ and $\emptyset$ belongs to $T$ and as $X$ belongs to $T$ and $\emptyset$ is open and it is belongs to $T$ becuase $T$ has every open set in $\mathbb R$
2. Union of any set of $T$ belongs to $T$ and as $T$ consists of all the open sets of $\mathbb R$ and X then union of open sets is also open so it will belong to $T$.
3. Intersection of any sets of $T$ belongs to $T$ which is also clear that $T$ consists of all the open sets including $X$ and $\emptyset$ so when we take intersection of any open sets of $T$ it will belong to $T$.

I tried this for A) part but I am confused for B) and c) parts

For B) part I did this:

Let $A=\{x,x,x,x,\dots\}$ and let $x$ is limit point of this sequence because it is a constant sequence so it will converge to $x$ and also there exist an open set $U$ in neighborhood of $x$ s.t $U\setminus\{x\}\cap A\neq\emptyset$ which satisfies the definition of limit point, therefore, every constant sequence has limit point.

Is this the correct way to prove part B)?

For C) let $x\in(a,b)$ and $0\in(c,d)$ s.t $c<a$ and $d>b$ then $x$ is also an element of $(c,d)$ which shows that $(a,b)\cap(c,d)\neq\emptyset$. So, for any two points of $\mathbb R$ we cannot find disjoint open sets in given $T$ for any disjoint elements of $\mathbb R$. Therefore $X$ is non-Hausdorff.

I will appreciate your help

Comment: Well...what have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $X$ is the only neighborhood of $x\in X$. (Why?)

Your approach for B) is not correct, you need to consider all sequences, not just a constanst sequence in $x$. Use the hint I gave for this.

In C) you start with "Let $x\in\dots$", but $x$ is already the name for our additional point in $X=\mathbb R\cup\{x\}$. Also just because a certain choice of open sets isn't disjoint doesn't mean there is no such choice, otherwise $\mathbb R$ itself wouldn't be Hausdorff, but it is. Again, the only neighborhood of $x$ is $X$, use this.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

A) As it stands, $T$ is not a topology as $\emptyset\notin T$. But I guess, they meant $T\cup\{\emptyset\}$, which *is* a topology. What you should verify is that:

> $X\in T$, and that 
>   $\,T\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is closed under finite intersections and arbitrary unions.

B) Prove that $x$ is a limit point of any sequence.

C) Show that $x$ and, say, $0\in\Bbb R$ cannot be separated by disjoint open sets.

Comment: Why $\emptyset\notin T$? It is open in $\mathbb R$.